# How safe is document.URL?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Lets say you are storing some information in the browser URL. You are then sending back the
URL to the server to do some validation. How hackable is the browser.URL object. Can some user easily change the value of URL in the memory?

Comment: Change the url in the brwoser? easy, never trust the client

Comment: if you want to pass some secure data to one page to another use post method ..its simplest way. or you can also send a data one page to another using encryption .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're specifically referencing `browser.URL` because JavaScript can only get it, not set it. But no one really has to hack `browser.URL` in memory or anything, they just need to type into the location bar whatever URL they want.

Answer (score 0):

`document.URL` is [not settable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.URL), but it is of course possible to manually alter any values in the URL by changing immediately in the navigation bar or by other means.

However, this should all be besides the point, because wherever you are "sending back the URL to the server", the user could easily manipulate what is being passed to the server, without changing `document.URL`.

Comment: The thing is even if you change the URL on the navigation bar document.URL will still return the original url. This might be the moot point like you said.

Comment: @specialscope: That doesn't make sense, if you navigate to a new URL, even if it's the same address with a different query string, there is no concept in which the URL you were previously at is "original". `document.URL` will always report the URL you're *currently* at, and even just a change in the hash will be reflected.

Comment: Hmm havent tried in my own page in web server but using chrome's console it seems to be the case. Eg. go to stackoverflow.com and start the console. Type document.URL, it gives http://stackoverflow.com. Next delete com and and do same again, it still gives http://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: deleting `.com` performs a google search for "stackoverflow" in my browser (chrome). Subsequent `document.URL` is `"https://www.google.se/search?q=stackoverflow&sugexp=chrome,mod=15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"`

Comment: Interesting! Well one thing is proved document.URL CANNOT be used for any sort of validation. Interestingly though my firefox also returns the originally typed url consistently even after deletion. I think I will check in another env later.